# How to make a conditional If statement that has to only meet a percentage of its conditions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements

Sometimes while coding apps and programs, in some situations, I would prefer if statements to work once a certain amount of conditions out of its total conditions have been met?

Such as the following:

```py
if (a>b andor a<c andor a==d): #if only 66% of the conditions are met
    print("Conditions have been met")
```

If there is any information on the topic/idea your help would welcome!

Comment: Seems like there's many ways to do this, what have you tried so far? The most obvious solution to me is to sum up the number of matches beforehand, and then compare the number of matches to the equivalent probability. However it's not clear if you've tried or thought about any actual solutions.

Comment: I tried doing it by making separate if statements, each one with one condition. If the condition is true, you add 1 to a counter and then a final if statement in the end to see if the counter equals a certain number...hold up- i just answered it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: as pointed out by u/schwobaseggl, you don't even need the conversion to `int`:

```
if sum([a > b, a < c, a == d]) >= 2:
  print("Conditions have been met")
```

---

```
if sum(map(int, [a > b, a < c, a == d])) >= 2:
  print("Conditions have been met")
```

This creates a boolean list with the result of each of the values, then converts them all to `1` if they're `True`, or `0` if `False`, then sums up the whole list, giving you the number of True conditions.

Note that this won't short-circuit, aka it will still evaluate all the conditions even if there are enough `True` ones in the first part of the list to ignore the rest.

Comment: You don't even need the int conversion. `bool` is a subclass of `int` and can be summed directly.

Comment: Interesting point about the short-circuit :) if you had lots of (ideally lazily generated) conditions and only needed few (`n`) to be true you could go with `if n in itertools.accumulate(conditions):`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```py
if(int(a>b) + int(a<c) + int(a==d) >= 2):
    print("Conditions have been met")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you create more conditionals, if you need that 2 out of 3 statements result in True to do the statement you could do something like this:

```py
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
if a > b and a > c:
    print("Do something")
elif a < c and a == d:
    print("Do something")
elif a > b and a == d:
    print("Do other thing")
```

And so on.

I think that is the best way to do, what you want. By the way `andor` isn't a keyword in python so it will throw an error.